# ValueError: time data 'Mon Mar 31 14:52:16 2014' does not match format "%d/%m/%Y"

Tags: python

I am trying to check the last modified date time of a file but can't compare the date because of its format :

```
BPath = r'Path\\Path\\'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(BPath):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".xlsm")):
            DateModification = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(BPath+str(name)))
            DateModification = time.strptime(DateModification, "%d/%m/%Y")
            TargetDate=time.strptime("01/01/2022", "%d/%m/%Y")
            
            if(DateModification>TargetDate):
                print(DateModification)
```

Struggling with the following error :

```
ValueError: time data 'Mon Mar 31 14:52:16 2014' does not match format "%d/%m/%Y"
```

What does this mean ?

Comment: The first time you are calling `strptime`, the time data does not have the format you are specifying. Try to change with `DateModification = time.strptime(DateModification, "%c")` (%c is the locale’s appropriate date and time representation which seems to be appropriate here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`time.ctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.ctime) returns a string of the format `'Mon Mar 31 14:52:16 2014'` while the format you provide to `strptime` is `"%d/%m/%Y"` - these do not match.

Use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(your_mtime).strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` instead of `time.ctime`.